# How to do number formatting in mvc3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to get the output `TotalAmount` ( for example: `1000000000` as `1,000,000,000` ) but  my code throws this error:

> [ Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. ].

Please give me solutions on my below context.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount.ToString("#,##0.00"))
```

Comment: did you mean @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => **modelItem** .TotalAmount.ToString("#,##0.00"))

Answer (score 3):

**Model**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,0}")]
public virtual Decimal? TotalAmount{ get; set; }
```

**View**

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one. ( it would handle even the nullable columns)

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:#,#.00}", Model.TotalAmount))
```